# Disqus iframe grows to fit it's content, makes it hard to link to

Tags: iframe, comments, anchor, disqus

This line of code:

```
<p class="comment"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>#disqus_thread">0 Comments</a></p>
```

Takes the user to a page with the Disqus comment system that reside in an iframe.

When the page loads, the Disqus iframe has a hight of 0 (zero). Since the iframe is positioned at the bottom of the page, the following happens:

1. During pageload, the page is calculated to x height and the page is shown at the absolute bottom of the page since the 0 height iframe is found at the bottom.
2. The Disqus iframe grows to a specific height and the page x height is increased.
3. The user now see the Disqus iframe at the bottom of the screen.

I wan't the user to se the top of the Disqus iframe at the top of the screen. Anyone knows how I can fix this?

Comment: That line of code you mention is just for the comment counts, do you mean the embed.js code? I'm also confused as to what the issue is, do you have any screenshots or a live demo?

Comment: It's ok, I fixed it by hacking the Disqus plugin, so that when the Disqus iframe is ready, the page moves to the location of the iframe.